# Part identification, or alternative part - 63 613 Power Management chip

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification

I have this part, which is the only component that has discernable discolouration, and which I would like to replace:

[image: Photo of faulty IC]

on the PCB of a non-functioning SMPS (12 V 3 A):

[image: Photo of bottom of SMPS PCB]

The only markings on it are '63 613' and a search shows up only this: [New original power management chip 63513 63 513 63613 SMD 6 foot power IC straight shot](https://www.yoycart.com/Product/523273962268/), but no data sheets seem to be available (unless I need to be searching for something other than "63613").

Does anyone know of an alternative name/code/identifier for this IC? Or a suitable replacement?

Here is a better close up photo:

[image: Closeup]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking for ic markings starting with 63, the [OB2263](http://www.s-manuals.com/pdf/datasheet/o/b/ob2263_r23_on-bright.pdf) and twins [HT2263](http://archive.espec.ws/files/HT2263.pdf) and [another duplicate](http://www.hfq123.com/uploads/soft/20150121/1421824916.pdf) seem a very good candidate.

The first datasheet shows Marking Information "63 YWW" which would be 2006, week 13.

[image]

My assumptions:

- Gate pin is connected by 22 ohm resistor and anti-parallel diode to a
  through-hole mosfet.
- FB pin and GND pin are connected to through-hole optocoupler located below silkscreen text D4 (like TYPICAL APPLICATION in datasheet). Note C3 on the PCB is the capacitor close to the optocoupler in TYPICAL APPLICATION.
- R5 and C1 form a RC filter connected to the SENSE pin
- the through-hole component between silk R1 and R2 is an elco, and forms with R1 a filter for the power supply to the chip as in TYPICAL APPLICATION.

Comment: Thanks for the analysis. I have added an additional photo showing the 63613 more clearly